# XML parsing error (android studio)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have made an `xml` file (using android studio), which allows me to have a tool bar throughout my android application. However, I just keep on getting the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar     
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
 android:elevation="4dp" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Errors:

```
Error parsing XML: XML or text declaration not at start of >entity

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 
>'/root/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.0_rc2/aapt'' finished with non->zero 
exit value 1
```

Comment: Do not ask such non-sense questions here.

Comment: You are missing quite a few <'s in your code:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> for starters

Comment: Missing **<**, **>**, **/**... Are you sure to know what an xml file is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"

    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

    app:navigationContentDescription="@string/abc_action_bar_up_description"

    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"

    app:title="@string/action_settings"

    />
```

this is another example

```
<RelativeLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="8dp"

        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

 

    <FrameLayout

        android:id="@+id/putPrefsContentHere"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. It works well. I have errors in other files now. Could you tell how to add code when asking questions? Goofed up in the question

Comment: you have to select the code text and use the  {} button , what errors you have ?

Comment: Error Corrected. I had created the tool_bar.xml file as an android resource file under my app and not specifically under the app/res/layout folder. Due to this acivity_main.xml could not connect to tool_bar.xml . Now that I have created the tool_bar.xml file under layout it works perfectly. I now have a action bar for all pages.

Comment: good, set as correct answer so it could be useful in future :)